# How to get similar words in wordnet (not just synonyms)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

How to get similar words using wordnet, and not only the synonyms using synsets and their lemmas?

For example, if you search for "happy" on the wordnet online tool (http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/). For the first synset there is only one synonym (happy) but if you click on it (on the S: link) you get additional words in "see also" and "similar to" words, like "cheerful".

How do I get these words and what are they called in wordnet terminology? I am using python with nltk and can only get the synsets and lemmas at best (excluding the hypernyms etc.)

Answer (score 3):

"also_sees()" and "similar_tos()".

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets("happy")[0].also_sees() 
[Synset('cheerful.a.01'), Synset('contented.a.01'), Synset('elated.a.01'), Synset('euphoric.a.01'), Synset('felicitous.a.01'), Synset('glad.a.01'), Synset('joyful.a.01'), Synset('joyous.a.01')]
>>> wn.synsets("happy")[0].similar_tos()
[Synset('blessed.s.06'), Synset('blissful.s.01'), Synset('bright.s.09'), Synset('golden.s.02'), Synset('laughing.s.01')]
```

If you want to see the full list of what a WordNet synset can do, try the "dir()" command. (It'll be full of objects you probably don't want, so I stripped out the underscored below.)

```
 >>> [func for func in dir(wn.synsets("happy")[0]) if func[0] != "_"]         
 ['acyclic_tree', 'also_sees', 'attributes', 'causes', 'closure', 'common_hypernyms', 'definition', 'entailments', 'examples', 'frame_ids', 'hypernym_distances', 'hypernym_paths', 'hypernyms', 'hyponyms', 'in_region_domains', 'in_topic_domains', 'in_usage_domains', 'instance_hypernyms', 'instance_hyponyms', 'jcn_similarity', 'lch_similarity', 'lemma_names', 'lemmas', 'lexname', 'lin_similarity', 'lowest_common_hypernyms', 'max_depth', 'member_holonyms', 'member_meronyms', 'min_depth', 'mst', 'name', 'offset', 'part_holonyms', 'part_meronyms', 'path_similarity', 'pos', 'region_domains', 'res_similarity', 'root_hypernyms', 'shortest_path_distance', 'similar_tos', 'substance_holonyms', 'substance_meronyms', 'topic_domains', 'tree', 'usage_domains', 'verb_groups', 'wup_similarity']
```